# Arduino Pro Mini automatically resetting

Tags: arduino-ide, uploading, arduino-pro-mini

I have an Arduino Pro Mini 3.3v in a robot. The problem is, the Mini would automatically randomly overwrite the uploaded sketch with the default blink sketch... And this is becoming quite a problem.

I have connected the Arduino to a L293D Motor Driver and the Arduino gets its power from the motor driver only. It will work just fine, but randomly will reset to the blink sketch...

Please help

P.S- It automatically corrected after a while

Comment: I think you are seeing the bootloader, not the blink sketch.

Comment: @Gerben whatever it is... My sketch isn't running!

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious cause for a reset is pulling to much current from the Arduino.  I have never heard of an Arduino downloading a new sketch to itself.  Is it possible you are seeing the board booting up and flashing the LED as its doing so?

If you are getting the power from the motor driver its possible you are either giving the board noisy/dirty power or the motor is pulling to much current and depriving the board of power.  I would run them on separate supplies (with a common ground) to avoid this.

Comment: I am providing ~18V (2 9v batteries connected in series) to the Motor driver. The motors can easily run on single 9v battery. I am clueless about what to do

Comment: Thats overvoltage, not over current. Connect the batteries in parrallel

Comment: The board may be resetting itself due to the overvoltage. Running the batteries in parallel should eliminate that as a suspected cause.